# площадь покрываемой фигуры из n прямоугльников

Tags: c++, алгоритм

> На плоскости дан набор из N прямоугольников, заданных массивом [x1, y1, x2, y2], где (x1, y1) координаты нижнего левого угла, а (x2, y2) координаты верхнего правого угла. Прямоугольники могут пересекаться и накладываться друг на друга. Найти площадь покрываемой ими фигуры.

С помощью какого алгоритма это реализовать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/873079/182825

Answer (score 0):

Сложить площади всех прямоугольников, вычесть площади попарных пересечений, добавить площади попарных пересечений пересечений, вычесть ... и т.д. рекурсивно пока есть пересечения.