# Алгоритмическая задача про прямоугольники на плоскости

Tags: алгоритм, структуры-данных

Как можно решать такую вот задачу: на плоскости заданы n прямоугольников со сторонами, параллельными осям координат. И нужно определить суммарную площадь регионов, покрытых нечётным числом прямоугольников. За асимптотику O(n log n).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/872858/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b2

Comment: Может, пригодится

Answer (score 0):

Использовать метод сканирующей прямой (sweep line)
([случайная ссылка](https://tryalgo.org/en/geometry/2016/06/25/union-of-rectangles/), [ыщо одна](https://www.hackerearth.com/ru/practice/math/geometry/line-sweep-technique/tutorial/)),
модифицировав подход для нечетного покрытия.

Comment: Пожалуйста, перенесите основное из текста по ссылке в ответ.

Comment: Хм.. Направление верное, но понадобится не только он.